# America's favourite Riley

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Unfortunately getting this one to rhyme is too hard, so I'll just spell it out.

My prefix was yours but is now ours
My infix is both a sea animal and a musician
My suffix is a place you might lose a shoe
I am something that is in the news almost every day

> The first 3 clues are all pop culture references, but they are quite well-known

Comment: If you're having trouble making it rhyme, then feel free to expand your riddle! Most enjoy a decent read when solving these too!

Comment: And here I was hoping you were talking about me.

Comment: I was confused by "Riley", so in case anyone else is: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6324/16581

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're

> BASEBALL.

My prefix was yours but is now ours

> All your base are belong to us. You have no chance to survive make your time.

My infix is both a sea animal and a musician

> I confess I don't know this one. Maybe SEB (there's a Sebastian in "The Little Mermaid", apparently, and there must be lots of musicians of that name)?

My suffix is a place you might lose a shoe

> BALL, as identified by El-Guest.

I am something that is in the news almost every day

> Indeed it is, if you're in the US. And arguably BASEBALL is America's favourite sport.

Comment: That is the correct answer!

Comment: The musician referenced in the infix was intended to be rot13(wbunaa fronfgvra onpu) but there are numerous possible correct answers there.

Comment: Nice answer!! :D

Comment: I confess it would never have occurred to me to call that particular musician by that name :-).

Answer (score 9):

Are you

> LUCILLE BALL?

My prefix was yours but is now ours

> Loose lips mean a secret was mine but now ours?

My infix is both a sea animal and a musician

> This is Seal.

My suffix is a place you might lose a shoe

> Cinderella at the Ball.

I am something that is in the news almost every day

> She’s America’s Favourite Redhead.

Comment: The suffix is right, the rest is wrong (including the final answer).  Unlike the other Rileys I've made today, this one is not a proper noun.

Comment: You are on the right track though by thinking that the answer could be described as "America's favourite xxx" for some value of xxx but you need to figure that part out on your own ;-)

Comment: Also, this one does not use homophones (I would have said if it did).

Comment: The suffix is right? I thought for sure I had the infix rather than the suffix haha